# refining navigation code for jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm working on a jquery plugin and trying to refine the code on the Next button.  The interface for the plugin looks like so:
[image]
The best thing is to just show you all my code first, then I'll draw your attention to my problem.
HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Carousel</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="button_carousel.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" carset="utf-8" src="button_carousel.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //December has 31 days, therefore 31 buttons are required.
    var appointmentDays = [4,7,21];

    function myEventHandler(idvalue) {        
      if($.isFunction(idvalue))return;      
      console.debug("myEventHandler fired...id: " + idvalue);       
    }

    var bc = $('#carousel').button_carousel({
      days_in_month: 31,
      starting_day: 4,
      days_with_appointments: appointmentDays,
      eventHandler: myEventHandler
    });     
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="carousel"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS button_carousel.css:

```
/* Styling for prev button */
#nav_previous {
padding:0 0 0 0;    
position:absolute;
top:5px;
left:5px;
width:30px;
height: 30px;   
}

#slides {
overflow:hidden;
/* fix ie overflow issue */
position:absolute;
width:300px;
height:33px;
border:1px solid #ccc;
top:5px;
left:47px;
background-color: #F5F6CE;
}

/* remove the list styles, width : item width=85 * total items=31 */    
#slides ul {
position:relative;
left:0px;
top:0px;
list-style:none;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;    
width:2635px;           
}

#slides li {
width:85px;
height:30px;    
float:left;
}

/* Styling for next button */
#nav_next {
padding:0 0 0 0;    
position:absolute;
top:5px;
left:364px;
width:30px;
height: 30px;   
}

#nav_previous a {
display:block; 
width:31px; 
height:32px;
text-indent:-999em; 
outline:0;  
}

#nav_next a {
display:block; 
width:31px; 
height:32px;
text-indent:-999em; 
outline:0;  
}

a#prev {
background:url(images/left_black_arrow.png) no-repeat; 
}

a#prev:hover {
background:url(images/left_white_arrow.png) no-repeat;
}

a#next {
background:url(images/right_black_arrow.png) no-repeat; 
}

a#next:hover {
background:url(images/right_white_arrow.png) no-repeat;
}

input.btn {
 height:30px;
 width:65px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 font-weight: bold;
 border:1px solid #000000;
}
```

JQUERY button_carousel.js:

```
(function ( $ ) {   

//grab the width and calculate left value
var item_width; 
var left_value;

//create the array of days
var day_names = new Array("SUN","MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT");

var btnDefaultBackgroundColor = "#F0F0F0";

var buttonSelected = 0;

var buttonVisible = 0;  
            
$.fn.button_carousel = function(newoptions){
  console.debug("initializing button carousel");
  
  //Set all the properties of the parent div element,
  //no matter what its name
  $(this.selector).css({"background-color": "#D4D6D7",
    "width":"400px",
    "height":"45px",    
    "margin":"0 auto",
    "position":"relative",
    "border":"1px solid #ccc"               
  });     
  
  //Set the defaults
  var defaults = {
    days_in_month: 0,
    starting_day: 0,
    days_with_appointments: null,
    btnAppointmentFontColor: "#FF33EC",
    btnSelectedColor: "#9BE3F7",
    eventHandler: null      
  };          
  
  var options = $.extend({}, defaults, newoptions);
  
  //Bind the eventHandler function to receiving id values from button clicks.
  //See trigger below from all button clicks.
  $(options.eventHandler).bind("CarouselButtonID", function(event,data) {
         //console.debug("bind event id: " + data);
         options.eventHandler(data);
  });
    
  //Create initial carousel interface
  var container = $(this);
  container.append('<div id="nav_previous"><a id="prev" alt="previous button"></a></div><div id="slides"><ul></ul></div><div id="nav_next"><a id="next" alt="next button"></a></div>');
  
  //Set the display property for all div elements
   $(this.selector).each(function(){
       $("div").css("display", "inline-block");
   });
  
  //Use event delegation for the previous and next buttons
  $('div#nav_previous').on('click', 'a#prev', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //get the right position            
    var left_indent = parseInt($('#slides ul').css('left')) + item_width;
    console.debug("prev button - left_indent: " + left_indent + " item_width: " + item_width);
    //slide the item            
    $('#slides ul').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 200,function(){    

        //move the last item and put it as first item               
        $('#slides li:first').before($('#slides li:last'));           

        //set the default item to correct position
        $('#slides ul').css({'left' : left_value});
    
    });
    //buttonVisible--;  
    //console.debug("buttonVisible: " + buttonVisible);
    //cancel the link behavior            
    return false;
  });
  //Use event delegation for the previous and next buttons
  $('div#nav_next').on('click', 'a#next', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //get the right position
    //console.debug("next button - calc: " + parseInt($('#slides ul').css('left')));
    var left_indent = 0;
    var calc = parseInt($('#slides ul').css('left'));
    if(calc == 0)
        left_indent = 0;
    else
        left_indent = calc - item_width;
    console.debug("next button - left_indent: " + left_indent + " item_width: " + item_width + " left_value: " + left_value);
    //slide the item
    $('#slides ul').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 200, function () {
        
        //move the first item and put it as last item
        $('#slides li:last').after($('#slides li:first'));                  
        
        //set the default item to correct position
        $('#slides ul').css({'left' : left_value});
    
    });         
    //cancel the link behavior
    return false;
  });

  
  
  //populate unordered list with input type button elements.
  populate_carousel();
  
  item_width = $('#slides li').outerWidth(); 
  left_value = item_width * (-1);
  
  //Use event delegation on the slide buttons.
  $('div#slides ul').on('click', 'li input.btn', function(event) {
    var currentBtnID = $(this).attr('id');
    if(buttonSelected > 0)
    {           
        $( "li input.btn#" + buttonSelected ).css( "background-color", btnDefaultBackgroundColor );
        $(this).css("background-color", options.btnSelectedColor);
        buttonSelected = currentBtnID;          
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).css("background-color", options.btnSelectedColor);
        buttonSelected = currentBtnID;
    }
    $(options.eventHandler).trigger("CarouselButtonID", currentBtnID);      
  });     
  
  
  //Use this public function to reload all new options
  this.reloadAllOptions = function(newoptions){
          
    options = $.extend({}, defaults, newoptions); 
    var container = $('div#slides ul');
    //remove all the buttons
    container.each(function(){
        $( "li" ).remove();     
    });
    //populate unordered list with input type button elements.
    populate_carousel();
    
    var left_indent = parseInt($('#slides ul').css('left')) + item_width;

    //slide the item            
    $('#slides ul').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 200,function(){    

        //move the last item and put it as first item               
        $('#slides li:first').before($('#slides li:last'));           

        //set the default item to correct position
        $('#slides ul').css({'left' : left_value});
    
    });
    
    return this.each(function(){
       console.log(options);
    });
  }
  
  //Use this public function to update and highlight those days that have appointments associated.
  this.setButtonAppointmentFontColor = function(buttonColor){
      if(buttonColor == null)return $(this);
      var newoptions = {
        days_in_month: options.days_in_month,
        starting_day: options.starting_day,
        days_with_appointments: options.days_with_appointments,
        btnAppointmentFontColor: buttonColor,
        btnSelectedColor: options.btnSelectedColor,
        eventHandler: options.eventHandler          
      };
      options = $.extend({}, defaults, newoptions);
      HighlightDays(options.days_with_appointments);
      return this.each(function(){
       console.log(options);
      });
  }
  
  //Use this public function to update and highlight those days that have appointments associated.
  this.setButtonSelectedColor = function(buttonColor){
      if(buttonColor == null)return $(this);
      var newoptions = {
        days_in_month: options.days_in_month,
        starting_day: options.starting_day,
        days_with_appointments: options.days_with_appointments,
        btnAppointmentFontColor: options.btnAppointmentFontColor,
        btnSelectedColor: buttonColor,
        eventHandler: options.eventHandler          
      };
      options = $.extend({}, defaults, newoptions);
      return this.each(function(){
       console.log(options);
      });
  }
  
  //Use this public function to update and highlight those days that have appointments associated.
  this.setAppointmentDays = function(apptDaysArray){
      if(apptDaysArray == null)return $(this);
      var newoptions = {
        days_in_month: options.days_in_month,
        starting_day: options.starting_day,
        days_with_appointments: apptDaysArray,
        btnAppointmentFontColor: options.btnAppointmentFontColor,
        btnSelectedColor: options.btnSelectedColor,
        eventHandler: options.eventHandler          
      };
      options = $.extend({}, defaults, newoptions);
      HighlightDays(apptDaysArray);
      return this.each(function(){
       console.log(options);
      });
  }
  
  //Use this public function to update the days in the month only
  this.setDaysInMonth = function(days, startDay){
      if(days == null)return $(this);
      if(startDay == null)return $(this);
      var newoptions = {
        days_in_month: days,
        starting_day: startDay,
        days_with_appointments: null,
        btnAppointmentFontColor: options.btnAppointmentFontColor,
        btnSelectedColor: options.btnSelectedColor,
        eventHandler: options.eventHandler          
      };
      options = $.extend({}, defaults, newoptions);
      var container = $('div#slides ul');
      //remove all the buttons
      container.each(function(){
        $( "li" ).remove();     
      });
      //populate unordered list with input type button elements.
      populate_carousel();
    
      var left_indent = parseInt($('#slides ul').css('left')) + item_width;

      //slide the item            
      $('#slides ul').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 200,function(){    

        //move the last item and put it as first item               
        $('#slides li:first').before($('#slides li:last'));           

        //set the default item to correct position
        $('#slides ul').css({'left' : left_value});
    
      });
    
      return this.each(function(){
         console.log(options);
      });
  }
  
  this.setEventHandlerFunction = function(someFunction){
      if(someFunction == null)return $(this);
      var newoptions = {
        days_in_month: options.days_in_month,
        starting_day: options.starting_day,
        days_with_appointments: options.days_with_appointments,
        btnAppointmentFontColor: options.btnAppointmentFontColor,
        btnSelectedColor: options.btnSelectedColor,
        eventHandler: someFunction          
      };
      options = $.extend({}, defaults, newoptions);
      
      return this.each(function(){
       console.log(options);
      });
  }
  
  this.setSelected = function(id){
      if(buttonSelected > 0)
      {         
        $( "li input.btn#" + buttonSelected ).css( "background-color", btnDefaultBackgroundColor );
        $("li input.btn#" + id).css("background-color", options.btnSelectedColor);
        buttonSelected = id;            
      }
      else
      {
        $("li input.btn#" + id).css("background-color", options.btnSelectedColor);
        buttonSelected = id;
      }
      //move the desired day of the month to the left side of the carousel
      if(buttonSelected == 1)
          return this;
      
      for(var i = 2; i < options.days_in_month + 1; i++)
      {
        if(i == buttonSelected)
            break;
        //get the right position
        var left_indent = parseInt($('#slides ul').css('left')) - item_width;
        
        //slide the item
        $('#slides ul').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 0, function () {
            
            //move the first item and put it as last item
            $('#slides li:last').after($('#slides li:first'));                  
            
            //set the default item to correct position
            $('#slides ul').css({'left' : left_value});
        
        });
      }
      return this;
  }
  
  this.triggerButtonClicked = function(id){
      $(options.eventHandler).trigger("CarouselButtonID", id);
      return this;
  }
  
  this.isAppointmentDay = function(id){
      if(options.days_with_appointments == null) return false;
      var appday = false;
      var day = 0;
      for(var i = 0; i < options.days_with_appointments.length; i++)
      {
          day = options.days_with_appointments[i];
          if(day == id)
          {
            appday = true;
            break;
          }
      }
      return appday;
  }
  
  function populate_carousel() {
    var index = options.starting_day;
    var container = $('div#slides ul');
      
    for(var i = 1; i < options.days_in_month + 1; i++)
    {
        container.append('<li><input type="button" id="' + i + '" class="btn" value="' + day_names[index] + " " + i + '"></li>');
        if(index < 6)
           index++;
        else
           index = 0; //reset           
    }       
    
    HighlightDays(options.days_with_appointments);
  }

  function HighlightDays(appointmentsArray)
  {
    if(appointmentsArray == null)return;
    //console.debug("HighlightDays(): " + appointmentsArray);
    resetButtonFontColor()
    var identifier;
    var match = false;
    $('li input.btn').each(function(){
        identifier = this.id;
        //console.debug("id: " + identifier);
        match = haveMatch(identifier, appointmentsArray);
        if(match == true)
        {
            $(this).css("color", options.btnAppointmentFontColor);
        }
    });
                
  }

  function haveMatch(number, appointmentsArray){
    var match = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < appointmentsArray.length; i++)
    {
        if(number == appointmentsArray[i])
        {
            match = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return match;
  }

  function resetButtonFontColor()
  {
    $('li input.btn').each(function(){
      $(this).css("color", '#000000');  //black 
    });
  }
  
  return this.each(function(){
     console.log(options);
  });     
};  

}( jQuery ));
```

Ok...so if you load up all the code as presented and click the NEXT button (that's the arrow button pointing right -->), you'll notice an anomaly with the way the DAY buttons advance.  The buttons are supposed to advance only one button at a time, however, the first time you hit the NEXT button 2 DAY buttons advance.  That's not supposed to happen. If you continue to hit the NEXT button, the DAY buttons advance one at a time thereafter.  The problem code is:

```
$('div#nav_next').on('click', 'a#next', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //get the right position
    //console.debug("next button - calc: " + parseInt($('#slides ul').css('left')));
    var left_indent = 0;
    var calc = parseInt($('#slides ul').css('left'));
    if(calc == 0)
        left_indent = 0;
    else
        left_indent = calc - item_width;
    console.debug("next button - left_indent: " + left_indent + " item_width: " + item_width + " left_value: " + left_value);
    //slide the item
    $('#slides ul').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 200, function () {
        
        //move the first item and put it as last item
        $('#slides li:last').after($('#slides li:first'));                  
        
        //set the default item to correct position
        $('#slides ul').css({'left' : left_value});
    
    });
    //cancel the link behavior
    return false;
  });
```

The arrow buttons are just anchor tags pointing to arrow images defined in the css, which you may need to play with to get something clickable.

I've been playing with this thing for hours and can't figure out why the buttons advance two DAY button on the first click. I need another pair of eyes on this problem because mine are glazing over.  Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes to your code:

```
 //Use event delegation for the previous and next buttons
    $('div#nav_next').on('click', 'a#next', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      //get the right position
      //console.debug("next button - calc: " + parseInt($('#slides ul').css('left')));
      var left_indent = 0;
      var calc = parseInt($('#slides ul').css('left'));
      console.log(calc);
      //  if (calc == 0)
      //    left_indent = 0;
      //  else
      //  left_indent = calc - item_width;
      console.debug("next button - left_indent: " + left_indent + " item_width: " + item_width + " left_value: " + left_value);
      //slide the item
      $('#slides ul').animate({
        'left': '-' + item_width
      }, 200, function() {

        //move the first item and put it as last item
        $('#slides li:last').after($('#slides li:first'));

        //set the default item to correct position
        $('#slides ul').css({
          'left': 0
        });

      });
      //cancel the link behavior
      return false;
    });
```

After the animation is complete you set the "left" value to item_width (-85px) also you move the element to the end of its parent. That result in -85px left margin with no element to fill it (we moved to the end of the elements) therefore the second element will fill that space.

Also, a working JSFiddle (minus the images): https://jsfiddle.net/0x402dte/